# Regular Expression to match text outside quotes etc

Tags: java, regex

```
"([\"'])(?:\\\\?+.)*?\\1"
```

I came up to this regexp to match all quoted strings..
It seems to work great...
The problem is how to match the text that isnt inside quotes..
The inverse -negative somehow...

I read the documentation and

```
(?!(([\"'])(?:\\\\?+.)*?\\1))
```

doesnt work

Comment: How does this work when you have a string that contains words with apostrophes?

Comment: you mean that? ' ?
it works because of the back reference \\1

Comment: This also presumes balanced quotes. It will fail in fragmentary situations, which may not be a problem for you but worth considering for completeness.

Comment: I mean with strings like; ***John said "What's going on, don't do that!".***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm If the first regular experssion works, I would use it to remove all quoted strings from the input string. Then, all you will be left with is the text that was outside quoted strings. With certain types of patterns, I find this approach much easier and simpler.

Comment: Also, you can `split` by the first regex, and keep the correct tokens.